# Wordpress 'on behalf of' email

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, email, smtp

Hi all the below contains example names so not to give my website away.

I have a wordpress site called blah.com that has a woocommerce shopping cart which is blah.com/products

When someone receives an email order confirmation it comes through as products@blah.com on behalf of 'Products catalogue [firstname.lastname@xyz.com]' in the header of the email in outlook 2013.

'[firstname.lastname@xyz.com]' is my personal email address and what I used when I first created the site for testing purposes.

'Products catalogue' is the name of the website (entered in the wordpress settings section)

When I use the Post SMTP plugin to send a test email its comes through correctly as products@blah.com [blah products catalogue]

Can anyone help me find where this email address is stored so I can change it to products@blah.com.

I have updated the email address in the wordpress General Settings page to products@blah.com where is was previously [firstname.lastname@xyz.com]

My email address at my hosting and email provider is products@blah.com.

I have updated the woo commerce email settings so that any emails that were previously [firstname.lastname@xyz.com] are now products@blah.com

I'm not sure what else to check? [firstname.lastname@xyz.com] must be stored somewhere in wordpress but I'm not sure where.

Many Thanks

Comment: Does this happen for all emails or just those from WooCommerce? What do you have set as your admin email in settings? And when you say on behalf of, can you ellaborate? I've never seen that before so I'm not sure if it's in the email content, or something your email client is reporting, screenshots would be helpful. Keep in mind though that WooCommerce questions are offtopic here, so if this is specific to Woo then you'll need to go to Woo support

Comment: The only form I have is the woocommerce ordering form so I'm not sure if it would happen with a non woo commerce form. 

When you receive the email in outlook where you have the sender displayed it is displayed as products@blah.com on behalf of Products catalogue <firstname.lastname@xyz.com>

The admin email is set to products@blah.com

Comment: What is blah.com in relation to you? Your site, a third-party WooCommerce plugin, or something else? More information we have (including what you have already tried) the easier it is for someone to write out an answer. As we are not a forum, each of us has one shot at answering per question. Help us to help you.

Comment: Apologies I have updated the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is one of the "two email settings you updated" the one at "WooCommerce > Settings > Emails > Email  Sender Options"?

Comment: I feel like an idiot :) Thank you

Comment: oh hey not at all, haha everyone misses stuff sometimes